# how to return an index from a function?

Tags: c++, function, return

I'm working on a phonebook program. I need to use a position returned by my findContact function and use it as an index in my deleteContact function.

```
void AddressBook::deleteContact(std::string nameMatch) //need to implement find contact && not found if there is a space at end of name
{

    if (length == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Phonebook is empty" << std::endl;
        return;
    }



    findContact(nameMatch);
    std::cout << phoneBook[position]->name << " deleted" << std::endl;
    phoneBook[position] = phoneBook[length - 1]; //how to use position
    length--;

    return;
}
```

I use a binary search because it is instructed by my professor.

```
int AddressBook::findContact(std::string nameMatch)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = length - 1;
    int middle;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
            middle = (first + last) / 2;


            if (phoneBook[middle]->name == nameMatch)
            {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            }

            else if (phoneBook[middle]->name > nameMatch)
            {
                last = middle - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                first = middle + 1;
            }
        }

        return position;
    }
```

It's mostly incomplete but I'm trying to figure out how to use the *position*

returned from my *findContact* function and use it in my *deleteContact.*

Answer (score 0):

Save the return value in a local variable.

```
auto position = findContact(nameMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *how to use position*. If your issue is, how you technically get *position* from your find method to your delete method, @DeviationN's answer is your solution.

But you're maybe asking *how* to do the deletion in your *phonebook* container (it's probably a vector?). What you've done is overwriting your entry to be deleted by the last entry in your phonebook. However, this is going to **violate the sort order** (in most cases). But if you use binary search, it is a **necessary condition** that your phonebook is sorted.

Instead, delete your entry at *position* via

```
phoneBook.erase( phonebook.cbegin() + position );
```

end either decrement your length as you did or reset it like

```
length = phoneBook.size();
```

(Here I have assumed that *phoneBook* is a std::vector or std::deque)

**Edit**: I just noticed that *phoneBook* is a container of pointers, so don't forget to do

```
delete phoneBook[ position ];
```

before erasing this element ( unless you use smart pointers ;).